# Python not working in web browser

Tags: python, linux

I am not able to execute python files in web browser but file can be executed from SHELL terminal.

**For Example:**

I have created a file under `public_html/index.py` with following code

```
#!/home/explore/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

print "Hello World!"
```

But when I am opening this file in browser, its just coming in simple TEXT.

**Note:** The `index.py` file is working fine, When I am trying to run this file by giving absolute path for both files in SHELL terminal using following command

**Error:** `/home/explore/bin/python index.py` This gives me error file not found

**Correct:** `/home/explore/bin/python /home/explore/public_html/index.py` Works nicely in shell terminal

Please Help, and tell what should i do?

Comment: How are you attempting to access `index.py`? Have you set up a server that knows to execute python code before serving content to the client?

Comment: I have followed this link to setup python http://blog.arvixe.com/create-your-own-python-enviroment-locally-in-your-shared-hosting-account/

Comment: all that link does is explain how to get python on a remote machine, not how to set up a server that is able to execute python code and respond to a web client with the code's output

Answer (score 2):

it's normal. The browser don't understand your python file. A browser can handle JavaScript, HTML, ... but no python files. This is why you will have plaintext file.

You need to create an HTTP server that will handle the python file.
You can check around: apache2 and mod_python, django (which is a framework written in python).

Another way would be to write your own HTTP Server in python and connect to it through the browser.
Then you can implement whatever you like. Try to do it by searching : "Python http server" in goodle. There is million of tutorials and guides on the web for that.

Have a nice day.
Kursion

*Ressources:*

**Django guides:**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/

http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-install-django-on-mac-osx-lion-10.7/

http://mirkobonadei.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/install-python-and-django-on-windows/

and so on

Comment: Is it necessary to install Django to run .py files in my server

Comment: I also installed Django with `/home/explore/bin/easy_install-2.6 django` still not working

Comment: You should execute this line in a terminal in the root directory of your Django project: `python manage.py runserver`. You should be able to get your page by going to the address http://127.0.0.1:8000/. More informations in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port